# Spring Cassandra is CachedPreparedStatementCreator class threadsafe?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, datastax

We are using Spring Cassandra and the datastax driver to make requests to Cassandra using CachedPreparedStatementCreator/PreparedStatement.  At startup,  these WARN messages are showing up in the log files (there are others, this is just an example of one)

> > :WARN lg:com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster - Re-preparing already prepared query insert into active  (id) values(?) USING TTL ?. Please note that preparing the same query more than once is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once.

The prepared statements are created using CachedPreparedStatementCreator class.   Looking at the source code, it appears that there is a ‘race condition’ and that the implementation is not threadsafe.

```
         Map<String, PreparedStatement> sessionMap = psMap.get(session);

        if (sessionMap == null) {

              sessionMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement>();

              psMap.put(session, sessionMap);

        }



        PreparedStatement pstmt = sessionMap.get(keyspaceCQLKey.toString());

        if (pstmt == null) {

              log.debug("No Cached PreparedStatement found...Creating and Caching");

              pstmt = session.prepare(this.cql);

              sessionMap.put(keyspaceCQLKey.toString(), pstmt);

        } else {

              log.debug("Found cached PreparedStatement");

        }
```

What is the intention for this class?   Is it intended to be threadsafe?  And would anyone have any information about the performance of this cache?

Comment: That's fixed with the Hopper SR2 release.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a race condition between checking for the statements existence and creating a new prepared statement. I would pursue a solution similar to the one in the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) docs.

Note that after the write lock is achieved there is a verification that the value still is not present. This would solve the condition you're seeing here.

Consider filing a ticket in the [Spring Data Cassandra](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS) JIRA or submitting a PR on [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra).